# Change scrollTo function to make next/prev image come to center instead of the left

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I have a horizontally scrolling div that contains images.

Using some jQuery, I have it so that clicking on the right half of the div scrolls to the next image, and the left half scrolls to the previous image. Currently, after the scrollTo function, the next/previous image comes to the left of the container.

How do I change it so it comes to the center of the container, and also change currentElement function to check when the image is centered.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var container = $("#sg-scroll"),
    child = $(".sg-pic_wrap"),
    current;

    // CURRENT ELEMENT CHECK
function currentElem () {
    child.each(function(){

        var x = $(this).offset().left,
            w = $(this).width();

        if (x <= 0 && x < w ) {
            current = $(this);
        }
    })
}

// MOVE TO ELEM
function scrollTo (elem) {
    container.scrollLeft(elem);
}


// CLICK
container.on("click", function(e){
    var _w = $(window).width();
    if ((e.pageX) <= (_w/2)) { // LEFT
        currentElem();
            if (current.prev().length > 0) { // otherwise we get undefined error
                scrollTo( parseInt((container.scrollLeft()) + (current.prev().offset().left) + 5 ) );
            }
    }
    else { // RIGHT
            currentElem();
            scrollTo( parseInt((container.scrollLeft()) + (current.next().offset().left) + 5 ) );
    }
});


// CURSOR ...
container.on("mousemove", function(e){
    var _w = $(window).width();
    if ((e.pageX) <= (_w/2)) { // LEFT
    }
    else { // RIGHT
    }
});

});//document.ready
```

Here is a  [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3zLg4p8v/)  for it being used in the gallery.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3zLg4p8v/7/ I've made some changes and it works fine. Might have some more bugs to fix. So not posting as answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yea the scrollTo works fine, it gets it centered. There only seems to be an issue with what it thinks the currentElement is, if you have manually scrolled. Only with the next button though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Check my `// CHANGED` comments in the JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/3zLg4p8v/6/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // cache here reusable elements
    var container = $("#sg-scroll"),
        child = $(".sg-pic_wrap"),
        current;

    // CURRENT ELEMENT CHECK
    function currentElem() {
        // .each() instead of for(i = 0; i < var;i++)
        child.each(function() {

            // these variables must  be updated each time
            // we launch the function, so we cache them inside
            var x = $(this).offset().left,
                w = $(this).width(),
                cW = $('#sg-container').width() / 2; // CHANGED

            if (x < cW && x + w > cW) { // CHANGED
                current = $(this);
            }



        })
    }

    // MOVE TO ELEM
    function scrollTo(elem, width) {
        elem = elem + (width/2) - ($('#sg-container').width()/2); // CHANGED
        container.scrollLeft(elem);
    }


    // CLICK
    container.on("click", function(e) {
        var _w = $(window).width();
        if ((e.pageX) <= (_w / 2)) { // LEFT
            // we only need to check the current element each time we click, not on scroll
            // doing this will result in faster js
            currentElem();
            if (current.prev().length > 0) { // otherwise we get undefined error
                //scrollTo( parseInt((container.scrollLeft()) + (current.prev().offset().left) + 5) );
                scrollTo(container.scrollLeft() + current.prev().position().left, current.prev().width()); // CHANGED
            }
        } else { // RIGHT
            currentElem();
            //scrollTo( parseInt((container.scrollLeft()) + (current.next().offset().left) + 5 ) );
            scrollTo(container.scrollLeft() + current.next().position().left, current.next().width()); // CHANGED
        }
    });


    // CURSOR ...
    container.on("mousemove", function(e) {
        var _w = $(window).width();
        if ((e.pageX) <= (_w / 2)) { // LEFT
            //change cursor here
        } else { // RIGHT
            // or here
        }
    });



}); //document.ready
```

Comment: Thank you, this works great! Is there also a way of easily adding a .animate in there so the scroll is animated, rather than it jumping to the image?

Comment: @Joe Yes, check this: https://jsfiddle.net/3zLg4p8v/9/ the only line updated have a comment '// UPDATED'. :)